# Prevent Accordion DIV from Dissapearing

Tags: jquery, accordion, fluid, toggleclass

I have a horizontal accordion-type series of divs, with a default width of 33.33%. I'm using Jquery to animate one of those divs to 60% and the other two to 15%, so I retain the full screen width.

However, hovering on div1 or div2 causes div3 (the right-most div in the row of three) to temporarily flash or disappear (I guess until Jquery animates it down to a width that doesn't kick it down to the next row in the grid).

Is there some way I can keep this flash from happening - maybe a CSS tweak? The solution is probably right there in front of me, but I'm having trouble seeing how I can prevent the bug without removing the grid's behavior.

My HTML:

```
<div class="grid grid-pad">
            <div id="div1" class="col-1-3">
                <div class="content">
                    DIV 1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="div2" class="col-1-3">
                <div class="content">
                    DIV 2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="div3" class="col-1-3">
                <div class="content">
                    DIV 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

[class*='col-']:last-of-type {
    padding-right: 0px;
}

.grid {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 755px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.grid:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.grid-pad {
    padding: 20px 0 0px 20px;
}

.grid-pad > [class*='col-']:last-of-type {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.push-right {
    float: right;
}

/* Content Columns */

.col-2-3 {
    width: 66.66%;
}

.col-1-3, .col-4-12 {
    width: 33.33%;
}

.col-1-6, .col-2-12 {
    width: 16.667%;
}

#div1 {
    background-color: blue;
    }

#div2 {
    background-color: red;
}

#div3 {
background-color: yellow;
}
```

And JQuery:

```
$('#div1').hover(function() {
  $(this).stop(true, true).toggleClass('col-2-3', [1000]),
  $('#div2, #div3').stop(true, true).toggleClass('col-1-6', [1000]);
});
```

And the JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yysNr/47/

Comment: Try using `.animate` . I don't think `.stop` has any effect on toggle class

Comment: Some info: I see the flash on the next line in Firefox 20.0, but not in Safari 5.1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a combination of CSS tweaks and jQuery adjustments based on Joe's answer to achieve the effect:

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="second">
      <div id="div1">&nbsp</div><div id="div2">&nbsp</div><div id="div3">&nbsp</div>
    </div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
  background-color: white;
  width: 60%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#second {
 white-space: nowrap;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: brown;
 height: 500px;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: tan;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#div3 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#div1').hover(function() {
  $('#div2, #div3').stop(true, false).animate({width:'16.67%'}, 500),
  $(this).stop(true, false).animate({width:'66.66%'}, 500);
}, function() {
  $(this).stop(true, false).animate({width:'33.33%'}, 500),
  $('#div2, #div3').stop(true, false).animate({width:'33.33%'}, 500);
});

$('#div2').hover(function() {
  $('#div1, #div3').stop(true, false).animate({width:'16.67%'}, 500),
  $(this).stop(true, false).animate({width:'66.66%'}, 500);
}, function() {
  $(this).stop(true, false).animate({width:'33.33%'}, 500),
  $('#div1, #div3').stop(true, false).animate({width:'33.33%'}, 500);
});

$('#div3').hover(function() {
  $('#div1, #div2').stop(true, false).animate({width:'16.67%'}, 500),
  $(this).stop(true, false).animate({width:'66.66%'}, 500);
}, function() {
  $(this).stop(true, false).animate({width:'33.33%'}, 500),
  $('#div1, #div2').stop(true, false).animate({width:'33.37%'}, 500);
});
```

And the result: http://jsfiddle.net/cPmDX/

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is to order the addition and removal of your classes so that the sum of the widths of your divs is never greater than 100%.  This means you need to use different order when hovering-out than when hovering-in, so a second function is in order, and a tiny delay to make sure 
that the expanding divs don't crowd over before the shrinking one makes room.

```
$('#div1, #div2, #div3').hover(function() {
  //when hovering in, make the other divs smaller first    
  $('#div1, #div2, #div3').not(this).toggleClass("col-1-6",[1000]);
  $('#div1, #div2, #div3').not(this).toggleClass("col-1-3",[1000]);
  //then make this one bigger
  $(this).delay(2).toggleClass("col-2-3",[1000]);
  $(this).delay(2).toggleClass("col-1-3",[1000]);
 },
 function() {
  //when hovering out, make this div smaller first
  $(this).toggleClass("col-1-3",[1000]);
  $(this).toggleClass("col-2-3",[1000]);
  //then make the others bigger
  $('#div1, #div2, #div3').not(this).delay(2).toggleClass("col-1-3",[1000]);
  $('#div1, #div2, #div3').not(this).delay(2).toggleClass("col-1-6",[1000]);
 }
)
```

If the divs always fit on the same line, you should never lose the right-most one to line wrap

Comment: Joe, this is great! I do have one question though - I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate .animate (or just put a duration into .toggleclass) without messing up the accordion. I've tried .animate() but it doesn't work the way I'm using it in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yysNr/58/

Comment: I've edited and put your durations back in.  It required a tiny bit of delay to keep them from overflowing the margin while animating.